# Pycharm import unresolved

Tags: pycharm

It can work but...
[image]

It is all fine until I create new python3.7.7 virtualenv

[image]

and I notice that **init**.py is different from before.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Oh...my fault...

File--->Settings--->Editor--->File Types ---> find Text ---> delete **init**.py

I really don't when and how I modified the config.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this could be happening. Below are several steps that fixes the majority of those cases:

**.idea caching issue**

Some `.idea` issue causing the IDE to show error while the code still runs correctly. Solution:

1. close the project and quick PyCharm
2. delete the `.idea` folder where the project is. note that it is a hidden folder and you might not be aware of its existence in your project directory.
3. start PyCharm and recreate the project

**imports relative not to project folder**

Relative imports while code root folder is not the same as the project folder. Solution:

1. Find the folder that relative imports require in the project explorer
2. right click and mark it as "Source Root"

**Editor not marking **init**.py as Python**

Which is the most illusive of all the cases. Here, for some reason, PyCharm considers all **init**.py files not to be python files, and thus ignores them during code analysis. To fix this:

1. Open PyCharm settings
2. Navigate to Editor -> File Types
3. Find Python and add **init**.py to the list of python files (screenshot) or find Text and delete **init**.py from the list of text files

[image]